# Use if statement to declare different class for devices

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is it possible to write something like the following?

```
//  MasterViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

if (device == iPad)
    @interface MasterViewController : UIViewController
else
    @interface MasterViewController : UITableViewController
```

In other words, is it possible for a universal app to be subclass of different view controllers depending on device?

Comment: No. You can't. Declaring compiletime stuff with runtime data is a nono.

Comment: Don't *declare* a different class at runtime, *instantiate* a different one.

Comment: @CodaFi Can you expound on **instantiate** in an answer? Using the template for Master-Detail. Doing almost all design in IB. It works better on iPhone to use a TableViewController, but I want the 'space' available in iPad, thus a ViewController.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't try to create a single class like that, create 2 classes instead:

```
@interface MasterViewController_iPhone : UIViewController
```

and

```
@interface MasterViewController_iPad : UITableViewController
```

Then in your code use the device idiom to decide which one to instantiate:

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    // create a MasterViewController_iPhone
} else {
    // create a MasterViewController_iPad
}
```